# How to add a reference line in Tableau to an axis which is not in a row/column?

Tags: reference, line, tableau-api, scatter

I've ran into a problem in Tableau. I'm trying to add 50,85,95 percentiles of total items on my sheet but i can't seem to solve the issue.

[Here is my scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYtOy.png)

[Here are all the selected items that i want to display 50% of them with a reference line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AojKS.png)

[Here is where i want the 50% line to be which is around half the total items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD4As.png)

Is this even possible here? I've tried dual axis, different columns and rows etc. nothing seems to work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you please better explain which is the condition that the reference line should represent?

It has to be something related to a measure

Comment: It should represent percentage of the total 'dots' currently visible. I have selected them all in the second picture and in the 3rd is where i want to have a line, at 50% of the total dots visible.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the axis, add reference line. a window like following screenshot will open

[image]

Tweak your changes as you like and Voila..